# Azure Function: Difference between AddOptions and Configure method of IServiceCollection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, azure-functions

I am using Options Pattern within Azure Function. I created custom classes to represent the config data.

Below is my settings.json

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
   
    "ServiceBusConfigOptions:EventTypeTopic": "",
    "ServiceBusConfigOptions:EventTypeTopicSubscription": "",
    "ServiceBusConfigOptions:ConnectionString": "",
    "ServiceBusConfigOptions:SendEmailTopic": "",
    "ServiceBusConfigOptions:NotificationMonitoringTopic": "",

    "EmailConfigOptions:FromAddress": "",
    "EmailConfigOptions:Subject": "",
    "EmailConfigOptions:MailingServiceAccount": "",
    "EmailConfigOptions:EmailTemplateDefaultValue": "",
   
  }
}
```

My EmailConfiOptions class:

```
public class EmailConfigOptions
    {
        public string FromAddress { get; set; }  
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        public string MailingServiceAccount { get; set; }
        public string EmailTemplateDefaultValue { get; set; }
    }
```

ServiceBusConfigOptions class:

```
 public class ServiceBusConfigOptions
    {
        public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
        public string EventTypeTopic { get; set; }
        public string EventTypeTopicSubscription { get; set; }
        public string SendEmailTopic { get; set; }
        public string NotificationMonitoringTopic { get; set; }
    }
```

In the Startup.cs class I can register with both methods AddOptions and Configure(as shown in the below).

So basically which method should we use? AddOptions or Configure.

```
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddLogging();
       
            builder.Services.AddOptions<ServiceBusConfigOptions>()
                .Bind(builder.GetContext().Configuration.GetSection(nameof(ServiceBusConfigOptions)));

            builder.Services.Configure<EmailConfigOptions>(builder.GetContext().Configuration.GetSection(nameof(EmailConfigOptions)));

            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IValidateOptions<EmailConfigOptions>, EmailConfiOptionsValidator>();
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IValidateOptions<ServiceBusConfigOptions>, ServiceBusConfigOptionsValidator>();

            
        }
    }
```

Comment: Internally, `Configure` calls `AddOptions`. [source code](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions/OptionsConfigurationServiceCollectionExtensions.cs,62)

Comment: @Nkosi Then, should we use Configure? Or it doesn't matter

Comment: Doesn't matter. Both shown code work the same.

Comment: This could help if you time to read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **ConfigurationBuilder** Class and the extension methods used to configure various files in your code.

In a **ConfigurationBuilder** we use **Configure** property to inject the settings of our custom or predefined services.

> which method should we use? **AddOptions** or **Configure**.

We can use both **Configure** or **AddOptions** to inject the ***IOptions***. But the proper way which follows to avoid conflicts.

If we are trying to inject the Custom ***IOptions*** in our Application, we need to use the **Services.AddOptions()**. to retrieve the exact ***IOptions*** value we need to use the **Services.Configure< IOptions>()**

```cs
public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
{
    # Inject Options
    builder.services.AddOptions();
    # it inject the Connection String value of ServiceBusConfigOptions 
    builder.services.Configure<ServiceBusConfigOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionString"));
    ...
}
```

#### Reference

- Usage of IOptions in Configure Link [1](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/options-pattern-in-net-6-0/) & [2](https://andrewlock.net/how-to-use-the-ioptions-pattern-for-configuration-in-asp-net-core-rc2/)
- Usage of IOptions in AddOptions Link [1](https://makolyte.com/csharp-how-to-supply-ioptionst/) & [2](https://www.davidhayden.me/blog/asp-net-5-configuration-and-ioptions)